# Intermittent System.InvalidOperationException thrown on ASP.NET MVC web application after an IIS reset on a web farm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, iis-8, appdynamics

We have a functioning `ASP.NET MVC 5.2.2` website running on `.NET Framework 4.5.1` hosted on a web farm with numerous servers. The web application integrates with AppyDynamics. The `AppDynamics .NET Agent 4.3.2.1` is installed on each server. *I noticed that it's an outdated version but we are unable to update yet.*

We use StructureMap for our IoC.

```
<package id="structuremap" version="3.1.1.134" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="StructureMap.MVC5" version="3.1.1.134" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="structuremap.web" version="3.1.0.133" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Sometimes something happens across the entire farm, perhaps by a:

- WebDeploy
- Server restart
- Manual IIS reset

There is a chance that one of the web applications on an affected node will not function properly. It will start up but the IoC never executed resulting in the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. 
---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

We can't prove it but we think that the AppDynamics Agent intercepts the IIS application just at the wrong time. The web application starts but the IoC is not configured hence the error above.

---

**My Questions**

1. Is this a known issue? *I really did search online*
2. If you have experienced this, do you have an idea of what the possible cause(s) can be?
3. How can we fix this annoying intermittent error for our customers?
4. Is it as simple as updating something? Like StructureMap & AppDynamics?

---

**Edit**

- The web application is deployed to a network shared folder which feeds all the web servers in the farm. :(
- The IoC setup must be working if it is working for all the other nodes. This problem seemed to have started since the installation of the AppDynamics Agents.
- It only happens if IIS is reset across the farm. One of the sites on that node will throw the error I mentioned above.
- *I am still investigating on my side*

`Application_Start()` from the `Global.asax`. For a crisp view of the image, click on it.

[image: Global.asax]

Comment: The error indicates you likely have startup code registered in the wrong order, allowing for the possibility that a controller will attempt to be created before the `IControllerFactory` or `IDependencyResolver` is actually registered with MVC. Please post the relevant startup code in `Global.asax.cs`, `Startup.cs`, etc. Specifically, where is your DI container registered with MVC?

Comment: It's strange though because the setup works. When there is a restart only one out of the 6 servers give us this problem. I am busy going through the Global.asax file to see if there is anything cooking there. I'll post it now but not sure if it will help without having reference to the rest of the code.